# Exporting visual studio project files

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, export

Im done with my first project and I wonder what my options are for exporting it.

I know I can create a .exe file but its a very small software so I dont want the user to have to go through the hassle of an installer for something that small. So I was wondering if I could maybe create a .msi file or something like that.. Packing all the files into 1 small exe or something. without sending them the folder with all the debugged files.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by export. Do you want the users of your exported file to have access to your whole solution and source code? If so, why not just zip your project folder?

Comment: Nono, I mean like "Deploy" I want to create a exe but without going through the hassle of the normal installer, im thinking about a ClickOnce at the moment

Comment: Well, if you just compile your project, it will not have an installation by default.

Comment: I mean, if it's a small app, can you not just distribute the exe itself?...Not every exe needs an "installer".

Comment: It needs all files from the debug folder to work :/

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio has an extension [MS Extension Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2014/04/17/visual-studio-installer-projects-extension/), all installers you create from Visual Studio 2012 on will have a one click installation. Its like deploying website will be very easy.